# I have to pass values from on page to another page using jquery, see the below code, & suggest me changes

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have to pass values from one page to another page with jquery function (& in url). Problem is that some values are dates (with slashs), that's why its not working properly. And i also want encrypt those values.

```
    function gotoreq()
    {     
         var baseurl = '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>';
         var d1 = $('#date1').val(); /*date with slashs*/
         var d2 = $('#date2').val(); /*date with slashs*/
         var pid = $('#prop_ids').val();
         window.location.href = baseurl+'controller/method/'+d1+'/'+d2+'/'+pid;
    }
```

Now I changed it to:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#reqBook',function (event) {           
             var d1 = $('#date1').val();
             d1 = d1.replace(/\//g, "-");
             var d2 = $('#date2').val();
             d2 = d2.replace(/\//g, "-");
             var pid = $('#prop_ids').val();           
             window.location.href = BASE_URL+'controller/method/'+d1+'/'+d2+'/'+pid;
        });
```

And In controller:

```
public function method($mov_in,$mov_out,$prp_id)
{        
   echo $mov_in.', '.$mov_out.', '.$prp_id; exit;
}
```

Its giving error of missing arguments

why this is happening?

Comment: you can use `session` to store data and pass it to the different view.

Comment: is there any special purpose to passing a variable using jquery? In CodeIgniter, you can pass a data to the view by using `$this->load->view ('viewDirectory/your_view_page',['data1'=>$data1.. so on..]);`

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
var date = $('#date1').val();
var d1 = date.replace(/\//g, "-");
```

same for second date and then pass it to url

Answer (score 0):

You can do this another way using **localstorage** to getting value from another page

Just write like this on page one.

```
localStorage.setItem('Date1', d1);
```

And get value from another page.

```
var date1= localStorage.getItem('Date1');
```